# Select object JQuery

Tags: jquery

I have HTML structured like this:

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        ...
    </ul>
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Is it possible to retrieve the HTML structure of the `ul` using jQuery?

I tried these, but it only returns the HTML of the child `li` elements, but I need to include the `ul` too:

```
$("div ul").html() 
// or 
$("div").children(":first-children")).html()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do, your question as it stands makes no sense at all.

Comment: I want the entire structure "<ul> <li> ... </ ul>"

Comment: `$('ul')` - like that.

Comment: $("div ul").html() (or $("div").children(":first-children")) returns me "<li> .... </ li>", but I want "<ul> .. </ ul>"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `outerHTML` property of a DOMElement to get the HTML output as a string that you require. Try this:

```
var ulHtml = $('div ul')[0].outerHTML;
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/k7zsfg2g/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the structure of the `ul` from above html, then You can try like this:

Html:

```
<div>
    <ul>
      <li>aaa</li>
      <li>bbb</li>
      <li>ccc</li>
    </ul>
    <div>3</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$('div:first ul').html();
// select first div by div:first then get the UL of this div
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/MLnBY/223/)